# Why VNC bash shell and remote SSH shell behavior different?

Tags: ssh, vnc

While login VNC desktop and open terminal invoking only HOME bashrc file executing but while login remote remote SSH it will invoking HOME bashrc/bash profile and also invoking LDAP bashrc and bash profile.

Why it behavior differently while launching shells.

Comment: The shell you launch in the desktop environment is not a login shell. The shell launched by the SSH server is. Therefore, the "VNC shell" does not execute the profiles.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` recognizes three shell states:

- login shell - shell instance that has been invoked directly by logging in to the server via eg. ssh or text console
- interactive shell - any shell where you can type commands, eg. shell started in graphical terminal. Login shell is also (usually) an interactive shell.
- non-interactive shell - this is usually shell invoked from within some program to run another program or command. As the name implies, in non-interactive shell there is no interaction with the user. For example, if you use ssh to run only a single command on a remote machine (like `ssh host.domain ls -l /etc`) then you are implicitly invoking a non-interactive shell on the remote machine and that shell in turn runs the command, and then quits.

How the startup files work:

- a **login shell** executes commands from `/etc/profile` (that's the global file for all users) and then looks for files `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or  `.profile` - in that order - in individual user's home directory, and executes commands from whichever file is found first. Usually by default on a newly created account only the `.profile` file exists, and by default it includes commands to execute contents of the `.bashrc` file also. However, you can remove the code to run `.bashrc` from the `.profile` file or you can create any of the other two files with the commands you need, and then `.profile` will not be run.
- an **interactive** (but **non-login**) shell executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` (that's global for all users) and then from `.bashrc` file in the individual user's home directory
- **non-interactive** shells started **locally** (ie. from within a program, or by typing `bash` in terminal window) do not run any of these files
- **non-interactive** shells started **from the network** (eg. in the above example where you run a command on remote machine via ssh) execute commands from `.bashrc` file in user's home directory only. However, the default `.bashrc` file often contains a piece of code at the beginning that stops further execution if the shell is non-interactive.

There are some more subtleties in specific cases, but basically it works as above.

When you connect via VNC and open a terminal, you are executing an interactive non-login shell. When you log in via ssh, you are executing a login shell. Therefore the difference.

Comment: See also the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). Furthermore, Bash can be made to behave like a login shell with the `-l` option.

Comment: Thank you for your support.Now understood.