# Different behavior between SSH into VM and running SSH commands from script

Tags: bash, debian, ssh

I'm relatively new to shell scripting, so I apologize if this seems like a simple question to ask. I have a linux VM (`debian, version 11 (bullseye)`) that I can ssh into (`ssh <ip>`), installed a few dependencies (homebrew, pyenv, etc) and was able to successfully use them. However, when I try running commands from outside of the VM (`ssh <user>@<ip> pyenv versions`) in either scripts or using my Mac terminal, I get `bash: line 1: pyenv: command not found` related errors.

I think this may have something to do with whats explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649166/why-vnc-bash-shell-and-remote-ssh-shell-behavior-different), but I'm not entirely sure how to circumvent that problem.

Adding additional details asked by @terdon in comment below:

```
$ which pyenv
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pyenv

$ grep /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile
grep: /home/f0p021s/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
/home/f0p021s/.profile:eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I've also realized that if I look at my path from within my VM it looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

And when I try to run a similar command from my local machine it looks different:

```
$ ssh <user>@<ip> 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you ssh into a machine, you start an interactive login shell. When you run `ssh ip command`, you are starting a non-interactive, non-login shell:

```
$ ssh localhost 'echo $- $0; shopt login_shell'
hBc bash
login_shell     off

$ ssh localhost
[terdon@tpad ~]$ echo $- $0; shopt login_shell
himBHs -bash
login_shell     on
```

<sub>See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695) for details on what this is actually showing you.</sub>

The files read on startup by each type of shell are different. From `man bash`  (emphasis mine):

> When  bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file **/etc/profile**, if that file exists.  After reading
> that file, it looks for **~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
> in  that order**, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
> exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
> shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for ex‐
> ample, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,  expands
> its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name
> of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following  com‐
> mand were executed:
>
> ```
>     if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file‐
> name.

Now, you have shown us that the `pyenv` command is added to your `$PATH` in `/home/f0p021s/.profile`. As you can see above, that file (`~/.profile`) is read by interactive login shells but not by non-interactive or non-login shells as those only read whatever is pointed to by `$BASH_ENV` and that is empty by default.

So, your options are:

1. Just use the full path to the command:

   ```
   ssh ip /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pyenv
   ```
2. Source `~/.profile`:

   ```
   ssh ip '. ~/.profile; pyenv'
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Your diagnosis is probably correct.

To circumvent the problem, you need to verify which rcfile is *not* executed at startup (it will likely be the one where PATH is set up), among the scripts in the answer you refer to.

Then, you could rewrite your `~/.bashrc` to avoid the problem.

Or you could try and change the command:

```
ssh <user>@<ip> '. /etc/profile; pyenv versions'.
```

This will import `/etc/profile` into the current executing shell. You might need to import `/etc/bashrc` or `~/.profile` instead of `/etc/profile`, or dot them both (note there is a space between the dot and the file name; also, the whole command is quoted).

## Testing (on Ubuntu)

Logging in on a handy virtual machine:

```
leonardo@aladdin:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
leonardo@aladdin:~$ logout
```

Now trying with straight SSH:

```
$ ssh leonardo@aladdin "echo \$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Okay. So, different PATHs. Where does, say, that java-8-oracle come from? **You will do some similar check, with some lengthy string in the PATH that is only there when in a login shell**.

As root from the VM, I look for that string following a PATH assignation, everywhere in `/etc` (should it not work, I'll retry with the home dotfiles by specifying `/home/.*`).

```
# grep -r PATH.*java-8-oracle /etc
/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh:setenv PATH ${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

The PATH assignment is there, plain to see.

And it comes from a file in "/etc/profile.d". Now a small bit of trivia is needed - knowing that the "whatever.d" folders are handy folders usually parsed from a *whatever* binary, and their contents is globbed sequentially.

So if the folder is `/etc/profile.d`, I expect this trick to be turned out by `/etc/profile`. Anyway, someone must meddle with "profile.d", so I can look for *that*:

```
# grep -r "profile\.d" /etc
```

And indeed I find, among several lines of output:

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/libreoffice.sh:# It is based on /etc/profile.d/complete.bash from SUSE Linux 10.1
/etc/profile:if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
/etc/profile:  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
/etc/apparmor.d/snap/abstractions/bash:  /etc/profile.dos                 r,
...
```

The second and third row are what I'm interested in. They say, "If there is a folder called /etc/profile.d, then; for each file ending in ".sh" in that folder, do...". This is *exactly* what I would have expected.

So, I can be confident that running `/etc/profile` will do the trick.

And indeed it works:

```
ssh leonardo@aladdin ". /etc/profile; echo \$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion with both profile and bashrc and didnt work. Is there anything you would recommend to read to try and diagnose the rcfile approach?

Comment: Add in each rcfile a line like 'echo Stating file`. Now login and compare the list of greeting lines with the expected list.

Comment: @FrankPinto some useful resources (some are my own, apologies for the self promotion, I just happen to know them): [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175), [Difference between .bashrc and .bash\_profile](https://superuser.com/a/183980), [Why are scripts in /etc/profile.d/ being ignored (system-wide bash aliases)?](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170), [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/879400) [Sequence of scripts sourced upon login](https://askubuntu.com/a/463479).

Comment: @FrankPinto did you try `ssh ip '. ~/.profile; pyenv`'?